# Writing out unit using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Which setting did I have to use to acchive the Unit is written out, using the package `siunitx`?

Little example:

```
\SI{8}{\m}
```

I would like the output like: "8 Meter"
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redeclare a unit to print something different

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\DeclareSIUnit\m{Meter}
\begin{document}
\SI{8}{\m} \SI{8}{\m\squared} \SI{8}{\m\per\second}
\end{document}
```

But consider also what this do to combinations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % version 3

\begin{document}
\qty{8}{Meter}, \SI{8}{Meter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

However, I wouldn't do this, it is not in compliance with *Système International d’Unités* (SI) nor with grammar of most languages. In the case that you like to spel out units name, than is better to locally write unit name. For example:

`A table is \SI{8}{meters} long.`

or in my language:

`Miza je dolga \SI{8}{metrov}.`

However, this is not grammatically correct in my language. it should be:

*Miza je dolga osem metrov.*

And BTW, isn't result of

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % version 3
\DeclareSIUnit\m{Meter}

\begin{document}
 \SI{8}{N\per\square\m}
\end{document}
```

silly?

[image]

Comment: So do I have to change all \SI{8}{\m} into \qty? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: @HConBike, no, not needed. I only use syntax of new version of `siunitx` (as is indicated in MWE), however it also works with use of `\SI`, see edited answer.